# Changing Style of Page (scene) programmatically, "Page.use_style=" not returning nil

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I want to change the [`Style`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/style) of a scene (programmatically called a [`Page`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/page)), using the [SketchUp Ruby API](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/).

To begin with, I'm just testing this through the [Ruby Console in SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/tutorial_console). I've prepended all the code I run with `>` for clarity.

Assuming I start off with all the [`Styles`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/styles):

```
> styles = Sketchup.active_model.styles
#<Sketchup::Styles:0xad9cd08>
```

I add a new `Style` to the "pool" of `Styles`, and check if I can reference it

```
> styles.add_style("MyStyle.style", false)
true
> styles["MyStyle"]
#<Sketchup::Style:0xad6f45c>
```

When I try to apply the `Style` to a `Page` (in the SketchUp GUI, a `Page` is called a scene) using [`use_style=`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/page#use_style=):

```
> pages = Sketchup.active_model.pages
#<Sketchup::Pages:0xad9cccc>
> pages[0].use_style?
true
> pages[0].style
#<Sketchup::Style:0xad7fdac>
> pages[0].style.name
[Design Style]
> styles["MyStyle"].name
MyStyle
> pages[0].use_style = styles["MyStyle"]
#<Sketchup::Style:0xad6f45c>
```

According to the API docs, `use_style=` **should always return** `nil`, so I feel like something is amiss here. In any case, here is what I get from `pages[0].style` after the code above is run:

```
> pages[0].style
#<Sketchup::Style:0xad7fdac>
> pages[0].style.name
[Design Style]
```

After looking around a bit more in the API, I found the `Page`'s [`update`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/page#update) method. Trying it out, however, yielded the same results. (In any case, I don't feel it's relevant here, as I think it's based on the current view on of the user.)

```
> pages[0].update(2)
true
> pages[0].style.name
[Design Style]
```

Am I missing something blatant here, or is the API just broken?

(I am running SketchUp 8.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
styles.selected_style = styles["MyStyle"]
pages[0].update(2)
```

---

The API docs isn't always correct. Some times the info is lacking, some times it's confusing, some times it's plain wrong.

`Page.use_style=` sets whether or not the Page (called Scenes now in SketchUp) will store the Styles. If you select your page (scene) in the Scenes toolwindow you see there is a series of checkboxes that let you save camera, hidden geometry, layers, section planes etc. This is the property you set with 
`Page.use_style=`

For instance, select a page (scene) and make a reference to it - keep the Scenes window open and types these commands:

```
page.use_style = false
UI.refresh_inspectors
```

Notice that the "Styles and Fog" checkbox got unticked. Also note that you need to call `UI.refresh_inspectors` in order for the UI to update when setting this property.